# Cuenta atrás utilizando una fecha con hora local

Tags: javascript, html, blogger, countdowntimer

estoy interesado en hacer una cuenta regresiva y estuve investigando las formas de hacerlo y no eh encontrado un resultado que se aproxime a lo que necesito. Quizás porque entiendo muy poco, puede ser, pero la idea es así: Necesito hacer una cuenta atrás básica, donde se pueda poner la fecha limite pero tomando el tiempo del servidor. Porque muchos códigos que he visto usan solo js y toma la fecha del cliente, entonces no es el mismo tiempo para todos.

Así que el código que estoy manejando hasta ahora, hace la cuenta regresiva (en este caso de ejemplo hasta el 30 Jun 2020 a las 4 am) y estaría necesitando poder definir mi hora local. Se podrá hacer alguna llamada a getTime(url) y poner un tercero como worldtimeapi.org para definir la hora local? Como lo podría hacer?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

HTLM

`<div id='contador'> </div>`

JS

```
function countdown(id){
    var fecha=new Date('2020','5','30','04','00','00')
    var hoy=new Date()
    var dias=0
    var horas=0
    var minutos=0
    var segundos=0

    if (fecha>hoy){
        var diferencia=(fecha.getTime()-hoy.getTime())/1000
        dias=Math.floor(diferencia/86400)
        diferencia=diferencia-(86400*dias)
        horas=Math.floor(diferencia/3600)
        diferencia=diferencia-(3600*horas)
        minutos=Math.floor(diferencia/60)
        diferencia=diferencia-(60*minutos)
        segundos=Math.floor(diferencia)

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=' ' + dias + ' Dia/s, ' + horas + ' Hs, ' + minutos + ' Min, ' + segundos + ' Seg.'

        if (dias>0 || horas>0 || minutos>0 || segundos>0){
            setTimeout("countdown(\"" + id + "\")",1000)
        }
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('restante').innerHTML=' ' + dias + ' D&iacute;as, ' + horas + ' Hs, ' + minutos + ' Min, ' + segundos + ' Seg'
    }
}

window.onload = countdown("contador");
```

Comment: `"cuenta atras usando la fecha del servidor"`, pero no hay codigo del lado del servidor que nos muestres, quizas estas usando `nodeJS`?, si ese es el caso porfavor edita las etiquetas de la pregunta y agrega a `nodejs`,  si ese no es el caso porfavor agrega el codigo de tu backend, ya que se supone que deseas usar es la hora del servidor, y no la hora del dispositivo en cuestion.

Comment: Con [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/UTC) podrías hacerlo, sólo necesitas convertir 30 Jun 2020 4 AM hora local del servidor a la hora correspondiente en UTC.

Comment: Como dice @Riven todo lo que has puesto es del lado del cliente, quizá si usaras por ejemplo PHP podrias enviarle a una funcion de JS el valor de la fecha y hora del servidor para luego hacer la cuenta atrás.

Comment: Tendrías que usar `Date.UTC` para las dos variables `fecha` y `hoy`, con eso todos los usuarios verían la misma cuenta atrás. Si te preocupa que algún usuario no tenga su dispositivo en hora entonces sí podrías usar tu servidor o un servicio externo para corregir el error.

Comment: Ok, ahí modifique la pregunta, no estoy usando un código backend, estoy insertando este contador en un gadget HTML/Javascript de Blogger, lo que me permitirá poder incorporar PHP también. En cuanto a lo que dice Juan.. se puede modificar la linea `var fecha=new Date('2020','5','30','04','00','00')` por `var fecha=new Date(Date.UTC('2020','5','27','07','00','00'))` y ya está? Ahí le calcule la diferencia, voy a probarlo y les digo.

Comment: Ahhh en `hoy` tambien, perdecto. En el caso de que quiera poner el servicio de un tercero como dije en el post, tendria que poner una variable con la url y agregar un getTime(url) en alguna parte o como modificaria eso?

Comment: Date.UTC te devuelve milisegundos, por lo que no hace falta que los conviertas a un objeto `Date` con `new Date` si sólo vas a usar el objeto para calcular la diferencia. En cuanto a obtener la hora actual, puedes simplemente generarla en el servidor (`var hoy_0=<?= 1000 * time() ?>;`), pero vas a introducir latencia posiblemente del orden de segundos.

Comment: Perfecto juanrpozo me ha funcionado! Muchas gracias